# update table using a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, sql-update, clickhouse

I have a *DataFrame*(`click_df2`):

```
        date  L120_active_cohort_logins  L120_active_cohort  percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins
0 2022-09-03                      45000              199000                             22.621906
1 2022-09-04                      40000              200000                             19.092138
```

Now based on this *DataFrame* I want to update values in table.

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS repeat_day_by_last_120_active_cohort_v1
        (
            date Date,
            L120_active_cohort_logins Int,
            L120_active_cohort Int,
            percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins Float
        ) ENGINE = MergeTree() 
ORDER BY date
```

Code is as follows this Is what I am trying to do:

```
    click_df2 = pd.read_csv(f'{location}/csv_files/main_data.csv',header=0)
    click_df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(click_df2['date'],dayfirst=True)
    client.execute(f'''ALTER TABLE repeat_day_by_last_120_active_cohort_v1 \
    UPDATE 'L120_active_cohort_logins' = "{click_df2["L120_active_cohort_logins"]}", \
    'L120_active_cohort' = "{click_df2["L120_active_cohort"]}", \
    'percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins' = "{click_df2["percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins"]}" \
    WHERE 'date' = "{click_df2["date"]}"''')
```

Data present in the clickhouse table repeat_day_by_last_120_active_cohort_v1:

```
        date  L120_active_cohort_logins  L120_active_cohort  percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins
0 2022-09-01                      32679              195345                             16.728865
1 2022-09-02                      32938              196457                             16.766010
2 2022-09-03                      40746              197586                             20.621906
3 2022-09-04                      33979              198799                             17.092138
```

after altering the table repeat_day_by_last_120_active_cohort_v1  data should be:-

```
        date  L120_active_cohort_logins  L120_active_cohort  percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins
0 2022-09-01                      32679              195345                             16.728865
1 2022-09-02                      32938              196457                             16.766010
2 2022-09-03                      45000              199000                             22.621906
3 2022-09-04                      40000              200000                             19.092138
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [to_dict('records')](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-to-dict) to run the mutation inside loop. Here is an example:

```
# docker-compose.yaml
version: "3"
services:
  click_server:
   image: yandex/clickhouse-server
   expose:
     - "8123"
   ports:
     - "8123:8123"
     - "9000:9000"
     - "9009:9009"
```

run `clickhouse` container: `docker-compose up -d`. Сreate a `.py` script:

```
import pandas as pd
from clickhouse_driver import Client


def print_clickhouse_data(client_: Client):
    print('clickhouse data:')
    print(client_.query_dataframe("""
        SELECT date,
               L120_active_cohort_logins AS logins,
               L120_active_cohort AS cohorts,
               percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins AS percent
          FROM repeat_day_by_last_120_active_cohort_v1
    """))


client = Client(host='localhost')
client.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS repeat_day_by_last_120_active_cohort_v1;')
client.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS repeat_day_by_last_120_active_cohort_v1
    (
        date Date,
        L120_active_cohort_logins Int64,
        L120_active_cohort Int64,
        percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins Float64
    ) ENGINE = MergeTree() 
    ORDER BY date
""")


# init clickhouse data
client.insert_dataframe(
    'INSERT INTO repeat_day_by_last_120_active_cohort_v1 VALUES',
    pd.DataFrame({
        'date': ['2022-09-03', '2022-09-04'],
        'L120_active_cohort_logins': [40746, 33979],
        'L120_active_cohort': [197586, 198799],
        'percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins': [20.621906, 17.092138],
    }),
    settings=dict(use_numpy=True),
)


print_clickhouse_data(client)
# your df for update(in your case from csv...)
click_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2022-09-03', '2022-09-04'],
    'L120_active_cohort_logins': [45000, 40000],
    'L120_active_cohort': [199000, 200000],
    'percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins': [22.621906, 19.092138],
})


# update data
for line in click_df.to_dict('records'):  # type: dict
    client.execute(
        """
        ALTER TABLE repeat_day_by_last_120_active_cohort_v1
              UPDATE L120_active_cohort_logins = %(logins)s,
                     L120_active_cohort = %(cohort)s,
                     percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins = %(percent)s
        WHERE date = %(date)s
        """,
        params=dict(
            logins=line['L120_active_cohort_logins'],
            cohort=line['L120_active_cohort'],
            percent=line['percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins'],
            date=line['date'],
        ),
        settings=dict(mutations_sync=2),
    )

    print('{} updated'.format(line['date']))


print_clickhouse_data(client)
```

run script:

```
clickhouse data:
         date  logins  cohorts    percent
0  2022-09-03   40746   197586  20.621906
1  2022-09-04   33979   198799  17.092138
2022-09-03 updated
2022-09-04 updated
clickhouse data:
         date  logins  cohorts    percent
0  2022-09-03   45000   199000  22.621906
1  2022-09-04   40000   200000  19.092138
```

See [mutations_sync](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#mutations_sync) setting